# Laravel 5.6 - Pass additional parameters to API Resource?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

A Laravel [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) can be either a single resource or a collection. In some cases, additional parameters are required to be passed to the resource/collection from the controller. Below is a simple example demonstrating the issue using `User` as a single/collection resource, and a custom `$apple` parameter to be passed to the resource for output. The  issue  can be seen in the final `Output (Collection)` below, where for the `fruit` value, we get an incorrect value of `banana` for the first user, instead of the correct `apple` value (which all other users get). It works perfectly for the single output, just not the collection. See below:

**Controller with UserResource (Single)**

```php
    $user = User::first();
    return new UserResource($user, $apple = true); // $apple param passed
```

**Controller with UserResource (Collection)**

```php
    $users = User::limit(3)->get();
    return UserResource::collection($users, $apple = true); // $apple param passed
```

**UserResource**

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Resources;
    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

    class UserResource extends JsonResource {
        private $apple;

        public function __construct($resource, $apple = false) {
            // Ensure we call the parent constructor
            parent::__construct($resource);
            $this->resource = $resource;
            $this->apple = $apple; // $apple param passed
        }

        public function toArray($request) {
            return [
                'id'     => (int) $this->id, 
                'name'   => $this->name,
                'fruit'  => $this->apple ? 'apple' : 'banana',
            ];
        }
    }
```

**Output (Single)**

```php
    {
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Peter",
            "fruit": "apple" // correct param!
        }
    }
```

**Output (Collection)**

```php
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Peter",
                "fruit": "banana" // INCORRECT param!
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Lois",
                "fruit": "apple" // correct param!
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Brian",
                "fruit": "apple" // correct param!
            }
        ]
    }
```

Please note that this is just an example, it can be any amount of random parameters (unrelated to the `User` collection, but must be passed for output logic), such as a single value `read_at` timestamp from a different table I want to pass once, and do some logic on it in the resource collection before output (like comparison to a user timestamp), or other parameters passed for additional logic `if/else` to be performed in the resource file in general to manipulate output of collection. How can this be done?

Comment: Where is the collection function code?

Comment: In Laravel codebase, I think it needs someone who's already familiar with Laravel's Resources (linked it btw above), who has faced this issue and solved it.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The following approach worked for me:

**UserResource**

```php
class UserResource extends Resource{

    protected $foo;

    public function foo($value){
        $this->foo = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray($request){
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'foo' => $this->foo,
         ];
    }

    public static function collection($resource){
        return new UserResourceCollection($resource);
    }
}
```

**UserCollection**

```php
class UserResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection{

    protected $foo;

    public function foo($value){
        $this->foo = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray($request){
        return $this->collection->map(function(UserResource $resource) use($request){
            return $resource->foo($this->foo)->toArray($request);
    })->all();

        // or use HigherOrderCollectionProxy
        // return $this->collection->each->foo($this->foo)->map->toArray($request)->all()

        // or simple
        // $this->collection->each->foo($this->foo);
        // return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

**Different ways to pass the additional parameter**

```php
(new UserResource($user))->foo('bar');
(new UserResourceCollection($user))->foo('bar');

UserResource::make($user)->foo('bar');
UserResourceCollection::make($users)->foo('bar');
UserResource::collection($users)->foo('bar');
```

Comment: I tried this `UserResource::collection($users)->foo('bar');` but got error `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::foo does not exist.`

Comment: @MunnaKhan ```foo``` is not static method. You are using ```foo``` as a static method. You need to instantiate the ```UserResource``` collection frist as in the answer.

Answer (score 23):

This is how I made it on laravel 8.

```php
class PatientResource extends JsonResource
{

  private static $data;
  /**
   * Transform the resource into an array.
   *
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   * @return array
   */
  public function toArray($request)
  {
    //access $data
    //self::$data
    return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'first_name' => $this->first_name,
      'middle_name' => $this->middle_name,
      'last_name' => $this->last_name,
      'contact_number' => $this->contact_number
    ];
  }

  //I made custom function that returns collection type
  public static function customCollection($resource, $data): \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
  {
   //you can add as many params as you want.
    self::$data = $data;
    return parent::collection($resource);
  }
}
```

Then on my controller I called that custom function.

```php
$data = PatientResource::customCollection($query->get(),$medicines);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can pass the extra parameters in as part of the call to the API endpoint.  You can then access the parameters with the $request object (for your example) in the UserResource.

For example, if you call the endpoint from a client such a web browser, axios, etc. using something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users?apple=true
```

this will make the parameter apple with a value of true available in the controller. Without any other action on your part it will then also be accessible in the toArray($request) of the UserResource.  You can access it similar to:

```
public function toArray($request) {
      $isApple = $request->apple;

        return [
            'id'     => (int) $this->id, 
            'name'   => $this->name,
            'fruit'  => $isApple ? 'apple' : 'banana',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Why I didn't think of this. Cheer!!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it's built-in!

Answer (score 9):

This simple trick worked for me in Laravel :)

**Controller**

```
$user = User::find($user->id);
$user->access_token = $tokenResult->accessToken; // Add additional data
return new ProfileResource($user);
```

**Resource**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'            => $this->id,
        'picture'       => $this->picture,
        'first_name'    => $this->first_name,
        'last_name'     => $this->last_name,
        'active'        => $this->active,
        'access_token'  => isset($this->access_token) ? $this->access_token : '', // Additional data
    ];
}
```

**Updated (June 2022) The same logic working for collections too**

User.php (model)

```
public static function getUserList(Request $request)
{
    $output = [];

    $query = User::query();

    if ($request->has('search')) {
        $query->where('first_name', $request->input('search'));
        $query->orWhere('last_name', $request->input('search'));
        $query->orWhere('email', $request->input('search'));
    }

    $queryActive   = clone $query;
    $queryInactive = clone $query;

    $output = $query->paginate(config('services.PAGINATE_PER_PAGE'));

    $statistics = [
        'total'    => $query->count(),
        'inactive' => $queryInactive->where('status', 0)->count(),
        'active'   => $queryActive->where('status', 1)->count(),
    ];

    $output->statistics = $statistics;

    return $output;
}
```

UserController.php

```
public function index(Request $request): UserCollection
{
    $users = User::getUserList($request);

    return new UserCollection($users);
}
```

UserResource.php

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first_name'                => $this->first_name,
            'last_name'                 => $this->last_name,
            'full_name'                 => $this->first_name . '' . $this->last_name,
            'email'                     => $this->email,
            'mobile'                    => $this->mobile,
            'gender'                    => $this->gender,
            'status'                    => $this->status,
            'status_title'              => $this->status ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
            'created_at_simple'         => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'created_at_simple_string'  => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->toFormattedDateString(),
            'created_at'                => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at_ago'            => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->diffForHumans(),
            'created_at_string'         => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->toDayDateTimeString(),
            'updated_at_simple'         => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'updated_at_simple_string'  => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->toFormattedDateString(),
            'updated_at'                => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at_ago'            => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->diffForHumans(),
            'updated_at_string'         => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->toDayDateTimeString(),
            'roles'                     => RoleResource::collection($this->roles),
        ];
    }
}
```

UserCollection.php

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data'             => $this->collection,
            'statistics'       => [
                'filters'    => request()->all(),
                'active'     => $this->statistics['active'],
                'inactive'   => $this->statistics['inactive'],
                'total'      => $this->collection->count(),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: what about collection? i have several data which i'm getting them base on `all()` and then returning like `DataResource::collection($data);

Comment: Didn't get your issue, what problems are you facing?

Comment: This is not resource collection

Comment: For collection, I have updated the answer.

Comment: What extra parameter/data are you passing in the 2022 example? still the access_token? I am going crazy trying to figure out how it is passed.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate you for your effort with this answer, but it is too ambiguous or bloated.  This is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689732/14669082

Answer (score 4):

To works with Laravel 5.7, I made some changes in relation to [Wonka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709050/746973)

**UserResource**

```php
    class UserResource extends Resource{

        protected $foo;

        public function foo($value){
            $this->foo = $value;
            return $this;
        }

        public function toArray($request){
            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'foo' => $this->foo,
             ];
        }

        public static function collection($resource){
            return new UserResourceCollection($resource, get_called_class());
        }
    }
```

**UserCollection**

```php
    class UserResourceCollection extends AnonymousResourceCollection {

        protected $foo;

        public function foo($value){
            $this->foo = $value;
            return $this;
        }

        public function toArray($request){
            return $this->collection->map(function(UserResource $resource) use($request){
                return $resource->foo($this->foo)->toArray($request);
        })->all();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue, by just retrieving the `$request->get('param')` inside the

```
public function toArray($request){ 

   $param = $request->get('param');

   ... 

}
```

Instead of passing the param through the Resource.

Answer (score 2):

you can **hack** request

in controller you have that

```
request()->request->add([ 'extra_data' => [ 'foo' => 'foo-value', 'other' => 'something', ], ]);
```

And in resource that

```
request()->get('extra_data') or $request->get('extra_data')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel 8

for store function Additional

```
    return (UserResource::make(User::find($user->id)))
            ->additional([
                'message'=>[
                    ['user by name: '.$user->name.' created successfull.']
                ]
            ])->response()->setStatusCode(201);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on **Laravel 8**

You can't use `additional()` on API resource **collection**

Below example doesn't work ✗

```php
ProductSizeResource::collection()->additional(['stocks' => $this->stocks]);
```

You need to append additional data to each resource individually

```
ProductSizeResource::collection(
   $product->sizes->map(
       fn(ProductSize  $productSize) => (new ProductSizeResource($productSize))->additional(['stocks' => $this->stocks])
   )
)
```