# send multiple data and show them in resource api laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 variables that I want to send to resource and show them via API like below:

```php
return new RoomDetailResource($data_array, $sum);
```

and the resource I have written is like below:

```php
class RoomDetailResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $sum;

    /**
     * Create a new resource instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($resource, $sum)
    {
        // Ensure you call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct($resource);
        $this->resource = $resource;

        $this->sum = $sum;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'sum' => $this->sum
        ];
    }
}
```

now what I get is the error:

> "message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", "status_code": 500,

but if I want to show `sum` it shows without any problem now here is how I want my API response to look like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    sum: 200
},
{
    id: 2,
    sum: 200
}
```

Note that `sum` is the same for all and I just want to repeat it in objects or show them at the end of the API response as a property.

thanks

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638257/laravel-5-6-pass-additional-parameters-to-api-resource

Comment: I don't know the data type of ```$data_array```. This link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections might be useful for you.

Comment: its an array  sorry i forgot to say

Comment: So the above link is definitely going to help you!

Comment: how it has writen nothing about adding data