# Laravel 8: How can I pass an additional parameter from controller to collection resource

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-8, laravel-collection

I want to pass an additional parameter from controller to collection resource, Please have a look at the following code, I don't know why It's not working. I might be doing something wron here, please help

**Controller**

```
$batchStudents = $batch->students->except($batch->host->id);
$batchStudents->test = 'This is testing';
$students = UserCollection::collection($batchStudents);
```

**Collection:**

```
    class UserCollection extends JsonResource {
    return [
            [...]
            'test' => $this->test,
        ];
    }
```

**Current Result:**
Cuurently its returning `null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.6 - Pass additional parameters to API Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638257/laravel-5-6-pass-additional-parameters-to-api-resource)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data